# Handling nulls in an audit/history update trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, null, sql-server-2008-r2

Say I have two tables, a "live" table and a history table.  The live table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LiveTable (
    LiveTableId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeVarChar VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SomeForeignId INT NULL,
    OtherForeingId INT NULL,
    ChangeBy VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    ChangeTime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

The history table looks the same, except it has its own primary key and an `IsDelete` column used elsewhere.  When a user updates a row in `LiveTable`, I want to log the row's prior values in the history table.  This is simple enough with an `UPDATE` trigger, of course.  But I've just determined that some of my updates aren't firing the history table insert, and I believe this is due to fields that allow nulls.  My trigger looks something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgLiveTableUpdate ON dbo.LiveTable FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.LiveTableHistory (
    LiveTableId,
    SomeVarChar,
    SomeForeignId,
    OtherForeignId,
    ChangeBy,
    ChangeTime
)
SELECT 
    d.LiveTableId,
    d.SomeVarChar,
    d.SomeForeignId,
    d.OtherForeignId,
    d.ChangeBy,
    d.ChangeTime
FROM DELETED d
JOIN INSERTED i ON d.LiveTableId = i.LiveTableId
WHERE d.SomeVarChar <> i.SomeVarChar
OR d.SomeForeignId <> i.SomeForeignId   //<--- I don't think this works
OR d.OtherForeignId <> i.OtherForeignId //<--- this either
```

Is it possible that my `WHERE` condition isn't hitting on situations where the change is to `SomeForeignId` or `OtherForeignId` because those columns both allow nulls?  If so, how would I write a condition that would take nulls into account when checking those columns for inequality?

Comment: Thought I think all of these answers would work, I'm a dork for the kind of stuff in @Richard aka cyberwiki's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also find the EXCEPTions, which give you the keys to record.

```
select 
    d.LiveTableId,
    d.SomeVarChar,
    d.SomeForeignId,
    d.OtherForeignId,
    d.ChangeBy,
    d.ChangeTime
from DELETED d
join
(
select LiveTableId, SomeVarChar, SomeForeignId, OtherForeignId from INSERTED
EXCEPT 
select LiveTableId, SomeVarChar, SomeForeignId, OtherForeignId from DELETED
) e on e.LiveTableId = d.LiveTableId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE d.SomeVarChar <> i.SomeVarChar
OR ISNULL(d.SomeForeignId,-987654) <> ISNULL(i.SomeForeignId,-987654)
OR ISNULL(d.OtherForeignId,-987654) <> ISNULL(i.OtherForeignId,-987654)
```

*note that -987654 is just some unused number from your ID column.  If it links back to an identity column -1 will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Not the question but consider stopping the update if there are no changes.

If there are no changes then then can prevent the update.

```
update live table  
set SomeVarChar  = 'a' 
where SomeVarChar is null or SomeVarChar  != 'a'
```

If it is just a single record at a time not a factor.
But A global update SomeVarChar  = 'a'  when 99% of the values are already 'a' is a lot of non updates.

Yes fix the trigger.

Something to consider if you are having performance issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...the where clause (or the EXCEPT in the accepted answer) prevents the triggered insert from happening anyway.  Are you saying that the performance issues would be caused by the execution of the trigger for all of those updates even if the insert didn't occur?

Comment: It was supposed to be != 'a'.